# Edits not displaying on device only on android studio

Tags: android

I set some buttons invisible on my android studio project, on the preview buttons disappears, when apk installed on phone i can still see buttons.

i already tried: Sync project with grandle files / sync with file sistem / Invalidate Caches Restart / Make project / Clean Project / Rebuilt Project / Disable instant run / Changeing run settings to: before launch grandle aware make / uninstalling android studio and re-installing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fab_gif"
        android:title="Gif"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gif"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fab_image"
        android:title="Image"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_image"
        android:visible="false"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fab_video"
        android:title="Video"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_videocam"
        android:visible="false"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fab_quote"
        android:title="Quote"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_quote"
        />
</menu>
```

So i have tried everything, and when i install my app on the android device is not showing edits that i have done in android studio. As you can see in the code i have a few buttons to hide so i just set android:visible="false" i also tried android:visibility="gone" but those buttons are still there in the app. What could i do to fix this problem ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Can you just remove those "unnecessary" elements from above `xml` file?

Comment: @Aryan have you tried any answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try and manage the visibility in your activity.

If you are using Kotlin use, i.e:

```
fab_video.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

If you are using Java.

```
View fabVideo = findViewById(R.id.fab_video);
fabVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to do it programmatically.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.fab_image);
            item.setVisible(false);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.fab_video);
            item.setVisible(true);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

This is going to hide your icons.